Trouble setting up PydanticOutputParser with LCEL RAG
I'm trying to set up a PydanticOutPutParser instance at the end of a RAG LCEL chain, but am receiving the error
TypeError: argument 'text': 'dict' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
This is my associated code
from langchain_core.runnables import (
    RunnableParallel,
    RunnablePassthrough
)
from langchain_core.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import (
    BaseModel, 
    Field
)
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema.output_parser import StrOutputParser

class Fee(BaseModel):
    fee_subject: str = Field(description="The subject in which the fee relates to.")
    fee_amount: float = Field(description="The dollar cost of the fee.")

class Fees(BaseModel):
    fees: List[Fee] = Field(description="List of fees.")

vectorstore = Milvus.from_texts(
    texts=all_texts, 
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(),
    connection_args={"uri": URI},
    drop_old=True
)

retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

pydantic_output_parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=Fees)

test_prompt = """
You are a fee-finding support assistant. Your job is to find any applicable fees relating to a person's query.
Return the fee and fee amount related to each part of a person's query.
If you don't find anything, then return $0. Do not make up fees. You are given supporting context to pull information from along with the original question.
\n{format_instructions}\n
Question: {question}
Context: {context}
Answer: """

test_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
    template=test_prompt,
    input_variables=['question', 'context'],
    partial_variables={"format_instructions": pydantic_output_parser.get_format_instructions()})

retrieval = RunnableParallel(
    {'context': retriever, 'question': RunnablePassthrough()}
)

model = Ollama(
    model="llama3",
    temperature=0
)

str_output_parser = StrOutputParser()

chain = retrieval | test_prompt_template | model | pydantic_output_parser

question = "I have a shipment being delivered to an airport. What amount in fees can I expect from shipping with XPO?"
output = chain.invoke({"question": question})

The error is happening when I invoke the chain. What am I missing here?
When I then change the output = chain.invoke({"question": question}) to output = chain.invoke(question), I get a new error
OutputParserException: Invalid json output: A treasure trove of fees!

The "treasure trove..." part is output from the model. It is not following the Pydantic output format. What is happening here, and why couldn't I use the dictionary format for invoke()?
FYI, I have the {format_instructions} in the prompt because that is what I did in a previous piece of code, but not sure if that is correct in this context.
